# Transparent icon in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm making a piece of software in VBA and the user clicks on an icon to takes them to a website.

The code is all working but I have one problem.

The userform has a background image and the icon no matter what file type (.jpg, .bmp) the icon's background is always white, even if the property is to transparent instead of opaque. Can anyone help?

I've seen about Microsoft Photo Editor but I can't seem to find it on my Windows 10 machine...

Comment: By "icon", do you mean an Image control?

Comment: Yes, sorry for the vagueness :)

Comment: Did you set the `BackStyle` to `fmBackStyleTransparent`?

Comment: Yes I did, but it still was white...

Comment: If the icon doesn't look too bad with 256 colors, a .gif would work

Comment: As long as the image actually has transparency (jpg and bmp do not support it), it should work. I'd suggest using a .gif (.png would be better, but it isn't supported by the control). If you simply need to find an image editor, that's a bit off-topic here.